# Plot columns of a data frame with the name of the column as a title

Tags: r

I'm trying to plot a graph for every column in a data frame setting the name of the column as the title of the graph. I tried to do it with a `for` loop and using the the `colnames` function, like in the example below.

```
a<-rnorm(1:10)
b<-rnorm(1:10)
c<-data.frame(a,b)
for (i in c){plot i, sub=colnames(c[i])
```

Tough, I get the following error: `Error in [.data.frame(c, i) : undefined columns selected` .
Can anyone help me with that?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop over the column names in `for` loop.

```
a<-rnorm(1:10)
b<-rnorm(1:10)
c<-data.frame(a,b)

for (i in colnames(c)) {
  plot(c[[i]], main = i)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the missing parentheses in your code the `i`s in your `for` loop give vectors and you attempt to subset your `colnames` with that. Also you may want to use `par` to display plots side by side.

You could either modify your approach by using a counter `ix`,

```
op <- par(mfrow=c(1, 2))  ## set par and store defaults
ix <- 0
for (i in d) {
  ix <- ix + 1
  plot(i, sub=names(d)[ix])
}
par(op)  ## restore par defaults
```

or loop over the column indices,

```
op <- par(mfrow=c(1, 2))
for (i in seq(d)) plot(c[,i], sub=names(d)[i])
par(op)
```

or loop over the names (which I show with `lapply` here).

```
op <- par(mfrow=c(1, 2))
lapply(names(d), function(x) plot(d[,x], ylab=x, sub=x))
par(op)
```

[image]

**Note,** how the labeling of the y-axis differs for the various approaches. Also note that we may use `names()` for the column names of a data frame which is slightly more concise (for matrices we need `colnames()`).

---

*Data:*

```
d <- structure(list(a = c(1.37095844714667, -0.564698171396089, 0.363128411337339, 
0.63286260496104, 0.404268323140999, -0.106124516091484, 1.51152199743894, 
-0.0946590384130976, 2.01842371387704, -0.062714099052421), b = c(1.30486965422349, 
2.28664539270111, -1.38886070111234, -0.278788766817371, -0.133321336393658, 
0.635950398070074, -0.284252921416072, -2.65645542090478, -2.44046692857552, 
1.32011334573019)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L
))
```

**Note:** Do not specify `"c"` as the name for objects, you will get confused with the `c()` function!